# Adding login with facebook to existing login with email authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've followed the Rails Tutorial, so I have a working email authentication system, that doesn't use Devise. I figured I'd add a Log In With Facebook button, so users have the choice of sighing up with email or Facebook.

There are many guides on how to do this, which I have successfully followed. I am able to get authentication back from Facebook.

What I'm not sure of is what to do with it. My User model has a password_digest field with a presence validation. Previously, all users had a password. But if a user signs up with Facebook, there is no password. Now I have two kinds of Users.

What do do? I could hack the code to account for the possibility of passwords not being present, but that seems sloppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are signing up a user with Facebook, you need to generate a random password in the backend and assign it to the user object. You can generate the random password using `securerandom`

```
require 'securerandom'
password = SecureRandom.hex(10) #=> "fe87683d536a51705357"
user.password = user.password_confirmation = password
user.save
```

This solution is used by many web apps, in the later stage if a user wants to login using a password the s/he can use Reset Password link to generate the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, cool, that was one of the workarounds I was thinking of trying. I wasn't sure if it was a best practice. I can give that a try. My other idea was to have a separate Authorizations object, but that is a fairly major change.

Answer (score -1):

Try using conditional validation. See example below:

```
validates :surname, presence: true, if: "name.nil?"
```

Comment: But wouldn't allowing nil password be a potential security issue? I don't want to allow somebody to easily log into accounts with no passwords.